# How to determine if an HTTP request is asynchronous in Python or Pylons

Tags: python, pylons

I can't help but think that this is a duplicate, but if it is, I can't seem to find the doppelganger.

I'm just starting to learn Python (focusing on Pylons) and I'd like to know if there is a way to determine if a call to a controller is done asynchronously or not. In PHP it would look something like this:

```
function isAjax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
}
```

Is there one that works well for all of Python, or is there perhaps one that works very well only in Pylons?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly translate that code to python using pylons you would do something along the lines of:

```
def isAjax(request):
    return request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REQUEST_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

where request is the request object passed to the controller.

Comment: @Keegan - Awesome! The reason I brought this up is because I was just reading [this section](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/exploring-pylons.html#request) in the Pylons book and I noticed how similar the environment variables are. I don't immediately have access to a server running Python where I can test this, so as soon as you or someone else confirms this, I will happily accept your great answer :-)

Comment: @treeface he's right... That's how you would do it. By the way that similarity you see is because the request.environ object it the same for all wsgi based python web frameworks. By which I mean pretty much every framework from web.py to pylons. Its all described in python PEP 0333 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) if you ever wanna look it up it's an interesting read.

Comment: So for the short answer: yes the method described by @Keegan will work with any wsgi based framework.

Comment: @Joshkunz Thank you very much! I've accepted the answer. Also thanks for the link...this is exactly the sort of response I was hoping to get. I love the Python community so far.

Comment: In my application I'm seeing HTTP_X_REQUEST*ED*_WITH, should I check for both?

Comment: @Joril: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Paste supports this method:

```
request.is_xhr
```

It's implemented as:

```
return self.environ.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', '') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```